# Asterisk Server with SIP Account Routing to Cell Phones

Tags: asterisk, sip, mobile-devices

I'm having trouble finding the exact documentation to do the following:

I have a SIP Account.  I want my Asterisk Server on a VPS somewhere in the United States to accept the credentials of the SIP Account.  When people call into my SIP account phone number at 111-222-3333 extension 55, it should re-route the call to my cell phone which is located somewhere in Canada.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?  Or refer to me the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got things to work.  This is EXACTLY what my sip.conf and extensions.conf looks like, I left all the other configuration files untouched

sip.conf -
a) replace [username], [password], [host] and [port] with the appropriate values

b) because my SIP provider is very finicky, I had to try various values for [host], and sometimes the [host] in the register => line was a different value from [host] in the host= line (but this may not be a problem for others)

```
[general]
register => [username]:[password]@[host]:[port]
context=default

[mysipprovider]
type=friend
secret=pass
username=[username]
host=host
port=5070
fromuser=[username]
canreinvite=no
;insecure=very
qualify=2000
dtmfmode=inband
nat=yes
```

extensions.conf

```
[default]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,n,Wait(1)
exten => s,n,Playback(vm-extension)
exten => s,n,WaitExten()


exten => 55,1,Dial(SIP/mysipacc/3332221111) ; extension 55 calls phone 3332221111
exten => 55,n,Hangup

exten => 66,1,Dial(SIP/mysipacc/1112225555) ; extension 66 calls phone 1112225555
exten => 66,n,Hangup
```

Answer (score 3):

You should do basically 2 things:

1. Setup Asterisk server to allow proper registration of your SIP account. This is done configuring the SIP credentials at /etc/asterisk/sip.conf
2. Configure Asterisk dialplan to map extension 55 as a dialout to your cellphone. This is done at /etc/asterisk/extension.conf

You will find extensive documentation about how to do this at the voip-info.org site: [sip.conf](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+sip.conf) and [extension.conf](http://www.voip-info.org/tiki-index.php?page=Asterisk%20config%20extensions.conf)). This other [link](http://www.beardy.se/2010/06/05/how-to-set-up-a-sip-trunk-in-the-asterisk-pbx) seems to be a good example of what you need.

Heres a small example on how it could look like:

sip.conf

```
[mysipprovider] 
type=peer 
secret=password 
username=2345 
host=sipserver.mysipprovider.com 
fromuser=2345 
canreinvite=no 
insecure=very 
qualify=yes 
nat=yes 
context=from-mysipprovider ; this section will be defined in extensions.conf
```

and at the extension.conf:

```
[from-mysipprovider]
exten => 55,1,Verbose(1|Echo test application)
exten => 55,n,Dial(SIP/mysipprovider/5551234); Here is the outbound call, the exact dialstring depends on outgoing provider and channeltype
exten => 55,n,Hangup()
```